# Convert pandas dataframe columns into nested python dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create python dictionary with pandas data frame column 2(source) and column 3(description) and group by column 1(title)
Also, I want to get values of only provided titles
titles = ['test1','test2']

```
   title  source description
1  Test1    ABC  description1
2  Test2    ABC  description2
3  Test2    DEF  description3
4  Test3    XYZ  description4

output = {'Test1':{'ABC':'description1'},'Test2':{'ABC':'description2':'DEF':'description3'}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for filter first, then is used [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with lambda function for `Series` of dicts and last [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
titles = ['Test1','Test2']

d = (df[df['title'].isin(titles)]
       .groupby('title')[['source','description']]
       .apply(lambda x: dict(x.to_numpy()))
       .to_dict())
print (d)
{'Test1': {'ABC': 'description1'}, 'Test2': {'ABC': 'description2', 'DEF': 'description3'}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can group by the dataframe w.r.t. title and then use python zip function to create inner dictionary with source and description. Please find below code for the same.

```
final_dict=dict()
all_groups = df.groupby('title')
for title in titles: 
    title_group = all_groups.get_group(title)
    source_desc=dict(zip(title_group.source, title_group.description))
    final_dict[title_group] = source_desc
print(final_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
result = {}

filter_ = ['Test1','Test2']

for x in df[df['title'].isin(filter_)].to_dict(orient='records'):
    result.setdefault(x['title'], {}).update({x['source']: x['description']})
```

---

```
{'Test1': {'ABC': 'description1'}, 'Test2': {'ABC': 'description2', 'DEF': 'description3'}}
```